# Divide an array into 2^N then add all the numbers in subsequent arrays together

Tags: c, arrays, math

I'm writing a program in C that uses threads to add up numbers from a partitioned array that uses some obscure command line arguments to determine how many partitions should be used.

This is a copy of the part I'm struggling with from my brief:

```
    Divide the array into 2**n partitions (n is another command-line argument)   and create 
 one thread to do simple sum of all values stored in one partition   of the array. Each 
thread can calculate which locations of the array it should   search given the thread index
 (0,1, … 2**n-1). For example, if n=1 and the   array is size 512, then thread 0 should sum
 array locations [0,255] and   thread 1 should search array locations [256-511].  Each 
thread should store   the partial sum it produces in a global array.  Note that since the 
threads do   not share any data, they do not need to be synchronized, however you do   need
 to wait until the last thread completes processing before continuing on   to the next 
stage.
```

I've absolutely no idea how to partition the array and why threads are even necessary for this task but seeing as it's part of my requirements I will have to use them. If someone could help explain a little clearer and the manor in which I'd go about the partitioning and the reason for threads, I'd be most grateful. I've already created the array and filled it with random numbers.

Comment: Is it some assignment/homework/contest question?

Comment: @anishsane yes it's an assignment. That said, I understand that on Stack Overflow you are no longer supposed to tag it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class might be parallel processing, and this assignment lets you do parallel addition on a given array with 2^n threads.

Comment: The course is in fact operating systems. 2^n threads is understood. n also had to be given as an argument so I've created an integer that stores 2^n. How would I go about partitioning the array 2^n times?

Comment: For example, when array size is 16 and n is 2, you can divide the array into 2^2 == 4 partitions, each has 4 elements, and let 4 threads to add up each paritions. Later you can sum-up result 4 values to get a grand total.

Comment: And.. your TA should be  your friend. :-)

Comment: The array size is also dynamically assigned. It's a bit late for the TA. I usually like to work this stuff out on my own but searching for C references is never that easy! How would one go about dividing the array?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can have multiple cores working on the problem at once.  It's clearly contrived to teach you threaded programming, but you'll need to start up the requisite number of threads and parameterize them with the correct starting point and amount of indices to process.

Your main thread will need to wait for them to complete and then add the partial sums from each.

Answer (score 1):

The partitioning is logical. You do not need to physically alter or divide the array.

Number each worker thread from 0 to 2**n.

Let `size_t` N = 2**n
Let `size_t` M = array length
Let a = the array of numbers

Thread 0: Calculate sum of a[0*M/N] up to, but not including a[1*M/N]

Thread 1: Calculate sum of a[1*M/N] up to, but not including a[2*M/N]

Thread j: Calculate sum of a[j*M/N] up to, but not including a[(j+1)*M/N]

Last Thread (j=N-1): Calculate sum of a[j*M/N] up to, but not including a[M]

All threads will access (different parts of) `a` simultaneously.

Note: Note that M/N will use integer division (intentionally).